# Us-100 ultrasonic sensor: zero result

Tags: c, arduino

I'm confused why the result is always zero
I'm sure I put the sensor pin correctly.
I've also used `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>` and that didn't work either.

So I'm worried that my sensor is broken.

does anyone have a solution or idea for my problem?
**Us-100 ultrasonic sensor[enter image description here][1]**

```
const int pingPin = 5; // Trigger Pin of Ultrasonic Sensor
const int echoPin = 6; // Echo Pin of Ultrasonic Sensor

long duration;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  Serial.print(duration / 29 / 2);
  Serial.println(" cm");
  delay(300);
}
```

`I tried again using serial with pins 12 and 13. it worked. Thank you to all of you.`

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
const int pin_TX = 12; 
const int pin_RX = 13; 
SoftwareSerial mySerial(pin_RX, pin_TX);
unsigned int HighByte = 0;
unsigned int LowByte  = 0;
unsigned int Len  = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  mySerial.flush();
  mySerial.write(0X55);                           // trig US-100 begin to measure the distance
  delay(500);                                  
  if (mySerial.available() >= 2)                  // check receive 2 bytes correctly
  {
    HighByte = mySerial.read();
    LowByte  = mySerial.read();
    Len  = HighByte * 256 + LowByte;          // Calculate the distance
    if ((Len > 1) && (Len < 10000))
    {
      Serial.print("Distance: ");
      Serial.print(Len, DEC);          
      Serial.println("mm");                  
    }
  }
  delay(1000);                                    
}
```

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of text output. Instead just copy&paste your output into the question.

Comment: You never print the result of `pulseIn`, but only the result of some integer division afterwards. You should first print the value you got to see what you really get. Also what values do you expect? For integer division you will only get values rounded down. You might try to convert to double before doing the division.

Comment: Small reminder: From [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Post the question and respond to feedback. After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments."

Comment: Thank you all, this has been resolved .I tried again using **serial** with pins **12** and **13**. it worked. But when i try pins **2** , **3** or **0** , **1** or **5**, **6** it doesn't work, I don't even know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use a different software approach, implementing a serial communication with TX-RX pins instead of sending and measuring pulses. This approach will check also if your device is working.

Please reconnect the connections of your device as follows:

```
Module Connection   Arduino Connection
VCC                 5v
GND                 GND
Trig                TX (Pin 1)
Echo                RX (Pin 0)
```

The code:

```
// RX (Pin 0 of Arduino digital IO) to Echo
// TX (Pin 1 of Arduino digital IO) to Trig 
unsigned int HighLen = 0;
unsigned int LowLen  = 0;
unsigned int Len_mm  = 0;

void setup() 
{   
    Serial.begin(9600);                         
}

void loop() 
{
    Serial.flush();                               
    Serial.write(0X55);                           // trig US-100 begin to measure the distance
    delay(500);                                   
    if(Serial.available() >= 2)                   // receive 2 bytes 
    {
        HighLen = Serial.read();                   // High byte of distance
        LowLen  = Serial.read();                   // Low byte of distance
        Len_mm  = HighLen*256 + LowLen;            // Calculate the distance
        if((Len_mm > 1) && (Len_mm < 10000))       // normal distance should between 1mm and 10000mm (1mm, 10m)
        {
            Serial.print("Present Length is: ");   
            Serial.print(Len_mm, DEC);             
            Serial.println("mm");                  
        }
    }
    delay(500);                                   
}
```

Great article here where you can find all the information:

http://arduinolearning.com/amp/code/arduino-and-us-100-ultrasonic-ranging-module-serial-data-mode-example.php

Hope this answers. All the best

Comment: Thank you all, this has been resolved .I tried again using **serial** with pins **12** and **13**. it worked. But when i try pins **2** , **3** or **0** , **1** or **5**, **6** it doesn't work, I don't even know why.

Comment: Thanks Nob. Happy you solved the issue. ,Please accept the answer so we can close the question, thanks